# Calling another page from Edit page throwing exception in Razor Pages

Tags: asp.net-core, navigation, razor-pages

I have edit page like this

[image]

i want to clone this page ,i have a clone button in this edit page like this

[image]

Given a link to navigate to clonepage something like this

```
<a asp-page="./RequestFormClone" asp-route-RequestID="@Model.RequestID" class="dropdown-item" style="margin-bottom: 0; padding: 3px 0px 4px 8px; cursor: pointer;color:black;">
                Clone Request
            </a>
```

But  when i click on the link i am getting this error

> InvalidOperationException: The model item passed into the ViewDataDictionary is of type 'ProjectName.Pages.RequestFormCloneModel', but this ViewDataDictionary instance requires a model item of type 'ProjectName.Pages.RequestFormEditModel'.

not really understood what causing this error,since i need to replicate the exact copy of RequestFormEdit, i just created another page RequestFormClone same as RequestFormEdit.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks,
Teena John

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> InvalidOperationException: The model item passed into the
> ViewDataDictionary is of type
> 'ProjectName.Pages.RequestFormCloneModel', but this ViewDataDictionary
> instance requires a model item of type
> 'ProjectName.Pages.RequestFormEditModel'.

That is because your page and PageModel does not match with each other.

Please check your PageModel name, keep the same with what you define `@model` in razor page.

That is to say, if you create a PageModel like below:

```
public class RequestFormCloneModel: PageModel   //PageModel name
{//...}
```

Your razor page should be like below:

```
@page
@model RequestFormCloneModel      //model name
```

Comment: thanks for the reply.Could you please explain what is the difference between these two lines of codes model RequestFormCloneModel and model ProjectName.Pages.RequestFormCloneModel. Because latter one was my code,when i changed it to yours its working fine.

Comment: Hi @Teena, I think you may not look carefully.  I think in your page it should be: `ProjectName.Pages.RequestFormEditModel` instead of `ProjectName.Pages.RequestFormCloneModel`. `RequestFormCloneModel `and `ProjectName.Pages.RequestFormCloneModel` should be the same, because the second one is just specific the namespace.  The error message is very clear that the PageModel and required model(`@model`) does not match with each other.

Comment: Any way, you just need be sure keep the same between the PageModel name in backend and the model name in frontend (`You can see the answer I share, it told you what is model name and what is the PageModel name`). That should be what you main concerned.